# How to reduce lifetime conflicts?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm fear about lifetime question. I searched and got so many relative results. I feel so different between of them, and I think it is difficult to get the spirit from them. so I decide to ask.

The error occurred when invoking `dao`'s method inside a Hyper service's call, and I can't fix it!

```
extern crate futures;
extern crate hyper;

use futures::future::Future;
use futures::Stream;
use hyper::server::{Http, Request, Response, Service};
use hyper::StatusCode;
use std::net::SocketAddr;

trait Dao {
    fn input_data(&self, data: &str) -> bool;
}

struct MysqlDao;

impl Dao for MysqlDao {
    fn input_data(&self, data: &str) -> bool {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

struct HelloWorld<'a> {
    dao: &'a Dao,
}

impl<'a> Service for HelloWorld<'a> {
    type Request = Request;
    type Response = Response;
    type Error = hyper::Error;
    type Future = Box<Future<Item = Self::Response, Error = Self::Error>>;

    fn call(&self, req: Request) -> Self::Future {
        Box::new(req.body().concat2().map(|b| {
            let rtn = self.dao.input_data(std::str::from_utf8(b.as_ref()).unwrap());
            let rtn = true; // line 35 this is ok
            match rtn {
                true => {
                    return Response::new()
                        .with_status(StatusCode::Ok)
                        .with_body(String::from("ok"));
                }
                false => {
                    return Response::new()
                        .with_status(StatusCode::UnprocessableEntity)
                        .with_body(String::from("error"));
                }
            }
        }))
    }
}

fn main() {
    let addr = "127.0.0.1:3000".parse().unwrap();
    static DAO: MysqlDao = MysqlDao;
    web_startup(&addr, &DAO);
}

fn web_startup<T: Dao>(addr: &SocketAddr, dao: &'static T) {
    let server = Http::new()
        .bind(addr, move || Ok(HelloWorld { dao }))
        .unwrap();
    server.run().unwrap();
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a5e515f48518bfba5f1341a5aff4626b&version=stable)

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/main.rs:33:9
   |
33 | /         Box::new(req.body().concat2().map(|b| {
34 | |             let rtn = self.dao.input_data(std::str::from_utf8(b.as_ref()).unwrap());
35 | |             let rtn = true; // line 35 this is ok
36 | |             match rtn {
...  |
47 | |             }
48 | |         }))
   | |___________^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime 'a as defined on the impl at 26:1...
  --> src/main.rs:26:1
   |
26 | / impl<'a> Service for HelloWorld<'a> {
27 | |     type Request = Request;
28 | |     type Response = Response;
29 | |     type Error = hyper::Error;
...  |
49 | |     }
50 | | }
   | |_^
note: ...so that the type `futures::Map<futures::stream::Concat2<hyper::Body>, [closure@src/main.rs:33:43: 48:10 self:&&HelloWorld<'a>]>` will meet its required lifetime bounds
  --> src/main.rs:33:9
   |
33 | /         Box::new(req.body().concat2().map(|b| {
34 | |             let rtn = self.dao.input_data(std::str::from_utf8(b.as_ref()).unwrap());
35 | |             let rtn = true; // line 35 this is ok
36 | |             match rtn {
...  |
47 | |             }
48 | |         }))
   | |___________^
   = note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
note: ...so that expression is assignable (expected std::boxed::Box<futures::Future<Error=hyper::Error, Item=hyper::Response> + 'static>, found std::boxed::Box<futures::Future<Error=hyper::Error, Item=hyper::Response>>)
  --> src/main.rs:33:9
   |
33 | /         Box::new(req.body().concat2().map(|b| {
34 | |             let rtn = self.dao.input_data(std::str::from_utf8(b.as_ref()).unwrap());
35 | |             let rtn = true; // line 35 this is ok
36 | |             match rtn {
...  |
47 | |             }
48 | |         }))
   | |___________^
```

The problem line is 34. When I replace line 34 with line 35, it works.

Comment: The closure captures reference to `self` which lives less than `DAO` reference in `self`. It can be mitigated by passing only the `DAO` reference into the closure. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=9ab0447a9c2b267a226d43faa72c609b&version=stable). Lines 30 and 33 are important.

Comment: @red75prime Do you mind if I write your suggestion as an answer and explain further why the lifetimes are this way?

Comment: Great! @red75prime ,If the compiler could give this advice. it will make rust easy to use!  I think the lifetime is one of the most obstacle in rust.

Comment: @red75prime I think it is a important thing for rust to make smaller the variable scope  to capture in closure,  it could avoid some queer compile errors

Comment: @DanHulme, sure.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of things going on with lifetimes in this code, and the error message is not that great.

The first thing is that your `call` function returns a *trait object*; that is, `Box<T>` where `T` is a *trait* instead of a concrete type. The default lifetime for a trait object is `'static`, so `Box<Future>` is equivalent to `Box<Future + 'static>`. That explains where this line of the message comes from:

```
note: ...so that expression is assignable (expected std::boxed::Box<futures::Future<Error=hyper::Error, Item=hyper::Response> + 'static>, found std::boxed::Box<futures::Future<Error=hyper::Error, Item=hyper::Response>>)
```

In this case, you don't need your returned `Future` to have the `'static` lifetime. Instead, you want it to have the same lifetime as `self.dao`, so change your type alias as follows:

```
type Future = Box<'a + Future<Item = Self::Response, Error = Self::Error>>;
```

The second thing is what variables your closure *captures*. Your closure refers to `self`, so it needs to save away that reference. This means the closure can't live past the end of the method - but you've already specified it will live as long as `'a`; that is, it will live at least as long as `self.dao`.

Note that `self` in this method does *not* have the lifetime `'a`. The instance of `HelloWorld` might have a shorter lifetime than the `dao` it has a reference to.

To fix this half of the problem, you need to allow the closure to capture *only* `self.dao` without capturing `self`. So you have to add

```
let dao = self.dao;
```

before the closure, and then refer to `dao` instead of `self.dao` inside the closure, so that it won't capture `self`. You also need to make the closure a `move` closure, otherwise it ends up capturing a reference to the reference, which still ties the lifetime to the scope of the function.

User [red75prime](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2731452/red75prime), who originally posted this suggestion in a comment, made [a playground with these changes](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=9ab0447a9c2b267a226d43faa72c609b&version=stable). Lines 30, 33, and 34 are the important ones.

Comment: Thanks for @Dan's elaborate explanation. I think I learned much about lifetime from you/!

Answer (score 0):

I found a way, but I think it's ugly.

Remove `dao` property from `HelloWorld`; add `Sync` to trait `Dao`; move out `DAO` to upper scope; invoke `DAO` directly from `fn call`.

Code : [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=1db88b5cbae4c9ad094294aff34679b0&version=stable)

Comment: [red75prime](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2731452/red75prime) gave an elegant solution.